# Python reportlab inserting image into table

Tags: python, reportlab

In the reportlab [user guide](http://www.reportlab.com/docs/reportlab-userguide.pdf) (page79), this is how the images are inserted into the table.

```
I = Image('../images/replogo.gif')
I.drawHeight = 1.25*inch*I.drawHeight / I.drawWidth
I.drawWidth = 1.25*inch
P0 = Paragraph('''
               <b>A pa<font color=red>r</font>a<i>graph</i></b>
               <super><font color=yellow>1</font></super>''',
               styleSheet["BodyText"])
P = Paragraph('''
       <para align=center spaceb=3>The <b>ReportLab Left
       <font color=red>Logo</font></b>
       Image</para>''',
       styleSheet["BodyText"])
data=  [['A',   'B', 'C',     P0, 'D'],
        ['00', '01', '02', [I,P], '04'],
        ['10', '11', '12', [P,I], '14'],
        ['20', '21', '22',  '23', '24'],
        ['30', '31', '32',  '33', '34']]
t=Table(data,style=[('GRID',(1,1),(-2,-2),1,colors.green),
                    ('BOX',(0,0),(1,-1),2,colors.red),
                    ('LINEABOVE',(1,2),(-2,2),1,colors.blue),
                    ('LINEBEFORE',(2,1),(2,-2),1,colors.pink),
                    ('BACKGROUND', (0, 0), (0, 1), colors.pink),
                    ('BACKGROUND', (1, 1), (1, 2), colors.lavender),
                    ('BACKGROUND', (2, 2), (2, 3), colors.orange),
                    ('BOX',(0,0),(-1,-1),2,colors.black),
                    ('GRID',(0,0),(-1,-1),0.5,colors.black),
                    ('VALIGN',(3,0),(3,0),'BOTTOM'),
                    ('BACKGROUND',(3,0),(3,0),colors.limegreen),
                    ('BACKGROUND',(3,1),(3,1),colors.khaki),
                    ('ALIGN',(3,1),(3,1),'CENTER'),
                    ('BACKGROUND',(3,2),(3,2),colors.beige),
                    ('ALIGN',(3,2),(3,2),'LEFT'),
                    ])
```

So based on the above user guide, i assume that to insert images into tables, all i have to do is import image using PIL, image module , load image and use it as data for table.

```
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import A4, cm,landscape
from reportlab.lib.styles import getSampleStyleSheet
from reportlab.platypus import Paragraph, Table, TableStyle
from reportlab.lib.enums import TA_LEFT, TA_CENTER
from reportlab.lib import colors
from PIL import Image as im
a=im.open("temp.jpg")
data=[['1',a],['3','4']]
c = canvas.Canvas("Reportlabtest.pdf", pagesize=landscape(A4))
table = Table(data, colWidths=200, rowHeights=50)
table.setStyle(TableStyle([
                           ('INNERGRID', (0,0), (-1,-1), 0.25, colors.black),
                           ('BOX', (0,0), (-1,-1), 0.25, colors.black),
                           ('BACKGROUND',(0,0),(-1,2),colors.lightgrey)
                           ]))
table.wrapOn(c, 200, 400)
table.drawOn(c,20,50)
c.save()
```

But instead of inserting the image into the table, i had this message created on the pdf "PIL.Jpegimageplugin.JPEGImageFile mode=RGB size=200x200 at 0x179B1E8"

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the **Image** of the ReportLab for image purpose instead of PIL.. hope it helps you. I have modified your code to below.

```
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import A4, cm,landscape
from reportlab.lib.styles import getSampleStyleSheet
from reportlab.platypus import Paragraph, Table, TableStyle, Image
from reportlab.lib.enums import TA_LEFT, TA_CENTER
from reportlab.lib import colors
from reportlab.lib.units import inch

a = Image.open("path/to/temp.jpg")  
a.drawHeight = 2*inch
a.drawWidth = 2*inch
data=[['1',a],['3','4']]
c = canvas.Canvas("Reportlabtest.pdf", pagesize=landscape(A4))
table = Table(data, colWidths=200, rowHeights=50)
table.setStyle(TableStyle([
                           ('INNERGRID', (0,0), (-1,-1), 0.25, colors.black),
                           ('BOX', (0,0), (-1,-1), 0.25, colors.black),
                           ('BACKGROUND',(0,0),(-1,2),colors.lightgrey)
                           ]))
table.wrapOn(c, 200, 400)
table.drawOn(c,20,50)
c.save()
```

**EDIT:** to import `cm` function, we should use:

```
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import A4, landscape
from reportlab.lib.units import cm
```

Comment: The function `open()` doesn't exist anymore in 2018. You have to send the parameters to the constructor. `Image("path/to/temp.jpg", 2*inch, 2*inch)`

Comment: It raises an error: `ImportError: cannot import name 'cm' from 'reportlab.lib.pagesizes' (D:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\reportlab\lib\pagesizes.py)`.

Comment: John - I'm always getting "module object not callable", I'm not trying to call it like an object, I'm doing the code just like in this excerpt. What should I do to solve this problem? I'm not using a buffer, I'm using getSampleStyleSheet() from reportlab...perhaps there are inconsistencies as it's an older library?