# Creating publication quality tables in python

Tags: python, tabular

I'd like to create publication quality tables for output as svg or jpg or png images using  python.

I'm familiar with the texttable module which produces nice text tables but if I have for example

`data = [['Head 1','Head 2','Head 3'],['Sample Set Type 1',12.8,True],['Sample Set Type 2',15.7,False]]`

and I wanted to produce something that looked like

[image: table image]

Is there a module I can turn to, or can you point me to a process for going about it?

Comment: I'd probably just generate some latex code and then render that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are large amounts of possibilities for you.

You can convert a Pandas dataframe to Latex as per https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_latex.html

You can also use Tabular to output latex source as per http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Tables

You can use ReportLab, as per [Python reportlab inserting image into table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17915879/python-reportlab-inserting-image-into-table)

You could also just write an HTML table file and style it with css.

```
with open("example.html", "w") as of:
    of.write("<html><table>")
    for index, row in enumerate(data):
        if index == 0:
             of.write("<th>")
        else:
             of.write("<tr>")

        for cell in row:
             of.write("<td>" + cell + "</td>")
        if index == 0:
             of.write("</th>")
        else:
             of.write("</tr>")

    of.write("</table></html>")
```

You can do something similar with Latex tables as an output.